# Dual visas of 2 different country

Tags: visas, usa, indian-citizens, philippines

Currently I am studying in the Philippines on the basis of my student visa/9f, but unfortunately due to some financial problems and family personal matters I cannot continue my studies anymore, and I have to go back to my country of India.  But after that soon I'll be going to USA for work, so could there be any kind of problem if I don't degrade my student visa to 9f visa, while getting and being approved for my working visa for the USA or any other country?

Answer (score 4):

Having a valid visa (of any type) from one country, does not bar you from having another visa from another country. It is a routine matter.

If you go to USA for work, all you need to ensure is that you have a proper work visa for the USA. Your student visa for Philippines does not matter either positively or negatively.

Comment: Depending on precisely what "for work" means, a business visitor visa (B-1) might be indicated rather than a work visa (for example H-1B).